# The parameter 'size' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type in Dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, null

I am new to flutter and dart , I have a problem where the parameter size cant have null value. I tried to search in the google the same problem that people had been facing and the solution is to add 'required'. i had tried that but the problem is in my body
Below here is my CustomCard().

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../constants.dart';

class CustomCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final Size size;
  final Icon icon;

  final String title, statusOn, statusOff;

  const CustomCard(
      { required Key key,
     required this.size, 
     required this.icon,
     required this.title,
     required this.statusOn,
     required this.statusOff})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomCardState createState() => _CustomCardState();
}

class _CustomCardState extends State<CustomCard>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late Animation<Alignment> _animation;
  bool isChecked = true;

  void initState() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 350),
    );

    _animation = Tween<Alignment>(
            begin: Alignment.bottomCenter, end: Alignment.topCenter)
        .animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _animationController,
        curve: Curves.linear,
        reverseCurve: Curves.easeInBack,
      ),
    );

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 140,
      width: widget.size.width * 0.35,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: kBgColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black12,
            blurRadius: 8,
            offset: Offset(3, 3),
          ),
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.white,
            blurRadius: 8,
            offset: Offset(-3, -3),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  widget.icon,
                  AnimatedBuilder(
                    animation: _animationController,
                    builder: (animation, child) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            if (_animationController.isCompleted) {
                              _animationController.animateTo(20);
                            } else {
                              _animationController.animateTo(0);
                            }
                            isChecked = !isChecked;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          height: 40,
                          width: 25,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            color: Colors.grey.shade50,
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                                blurRadius: 0,
                                offset: Offset(3, 3),
                              ),
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.black12,
                                blurRadius: 5,
                                offset: Offset(-3, -3),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: _animation.value,
                            child: Container(
                              height: 15,
                              width: 15,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 2, horizontal: 1),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: isChecked
                                    ? Colors.grey.shade300
                                    : kGreenColor,
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(
                widget.title,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: kBlueColor,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                isChecked ? widget.statusOff : widget.statusOn,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: kGreenColor,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

And below here is my Body.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:neew/constants.dart';
import 'package:neew/MainScreen/custom_card.dart';

class MainScreenBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenBodyState createState() => _MainScreenBodyState();
}

class _MainScreenBodyState extends State<MainScreenBody> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.1),
          Center(
            child: Text(
              "My Home",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 25,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.05),
          
          CustomCard(
            size: size,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home_outlined,
              size: 55,
              color: Colors.grey.shade400,
            ),
            title: 'Entry',
            statusOn: 'OPEN',
            statusOff: 'LOCKED',
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error that i detect in body dart is in CustomCard().
Please help me, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Is size field mandatory?

Comment: yes it is mandatory

Comment: Your code is working fine when I tried.

Comment: i failed to build, the argument doesnt match, then i tried to delete the key and super key, and suddenly it work lmao

Comment: so now code is working right?

Comment: Yes , thank you so much